# Excel Conditional Formatting Contains Text in Another Cell

Tags: excel

I have a data table where the certain types of products are allowed in certain bins. I have 2 tables and one is being used a reference a vlookup off it to this one below. Basically I want to highlight cells if they do contain a valid product type. So in this example the 3rd line would show up red and the rest would stay the same. Any ideas? I have been struggling with this.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the formula(s) you have tried? It may also be useful to see your lookup table. Why would the third line be red and not the second one?

Comment: You can use `NOT`,  `ISNUMBER` , and `FIND`.

Comment: @amcclay When you say "3rd line", do you mean "3rd row of the worksheet" (26 | 26 | 26, 40, 24), or "3rd row of the table" (3 | 8 | 26, 40, 28)?  Which values are you doing the lookup on, and what are you looking for them in?  Better examples of inputs and desired outputs would be useful.

Comment: @Chronocidal I meant the 3rd row of the table. The 3 doesn't exist in the 26, 40, 28. If a 26, 40, 28 were to show up nothing happens but if it doesn't then it shows up red.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the 2nd row would show up red because the 26 shows up in the the possible group IDs column. The lookup table is simply saying these bins can have then product group ids. This table says this bin has this product and this is the product group id for that product. Should it be there? No then red...yes then nothing

Comment: Assuming `ProductGroupID` is in column A, try `=ISERROR(FIND(" "&A2&","," "&C2&","))` if you want to apply down from the second row. If you want to apply it to the whole column, try `=IF(ROW(A1)=1,FALSE,ISERROR(FIND(" "&A1&","," "&C1&",")))`. You could also use `NOT(ISNUMBER(` instead of `ISERROR(` like suggested by BigBen.